# Any advantage of logging multiple things in one line rather than logging multiple lines?

Tags: java, logging

Is there any advantage of writing like this:

```
logger.info("[Request]: {}, [Response]: {}", requestObject, responseObject);
```

rather writing like:

```
logger.info("[Request]: {}", requestObject);
logger.info("[Response]: {}", responseObject);
```

Comment: You have everything in one line (so less clutter in your logs and it's easier to find related stuff if you put it in the same line) and make less calls to `info()`. That doesn't mean you always have to log everything in one line, but grouping related things certainly isn't a bad idea.

Comment: But this is the happy flow right? What if something bad happens and an exception is throw and the flow wont reach the end, in that case I wont be able to log request, that was be bad right?

Comment: Normally you'd catch exceptions and log whatever you need along with dealing with the exception or re-throwing it.

Answer (score 1):

One big advantage is being able to search for things that happened (e.g., with `grep`) and being able to get all the relevant info in the results, instead of having to open the file, search for whatever you want (e.g, some property of the request) and then having to scroll down to see the related info (in this example - the response details).

Comment: If that’s the only reason then you could just tell `grep` to displays some lines of context, e.g. `grep -A 1 '\[Request\]' my.log`. Of course when the application is multithreaded you’d now have to use synchronisation to ensure that related lines end up adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're working in a multiple-threads context.

- One-line logging: **Easy to see the related things in a group**
- Multiple-lines logging: **The next line and the previous line might be not relevant**

Answer (score 1):

In case of multiple lines and two parallel request you couldn't say which [Response] belongs to which [Request]. You would need some kind of an additional field like requestId to correlate them (which is quite useful anyways).